# Telegram t.me on Android

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I'm publishing a link to my Telegram bot using the above format. It works well, but if you don't have Telegram installed, it presents you with a download link that goes down the route of installing an 'unknown' app.

In tiny font at the bottom of the page you get a link to the Play Store. My problem is that most people are going to look at that and run a mile, as it looks dodgy and not even see the Play Store option. Is there a way of bypassing the dodgy-looking option?